# Send GET to service with Basic Authentication ASP .NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, httpclient, basic-authentication

I would like to send GET Request to a service which is secured with Basic Authentication (so the address is: https...). 
How can I do that in MVC? How can I put login and password to the request to be authenticated by this service?

Comment: Are you asking how to use https, or how to send credentials to the service?

Comment: I don't think this question has anything to do with asp.net mvc.

Comment: I want to send GET request to address:
https api2.orange.pl/sendsms/?from=xxxxxxxxx&to=xxxxxxxxx&msg=xyz

where auth data are:
login: LLLL
pass: PPPP

in ASP.NET MVC.

Answer (score 0):

That is what I expected and finally got it:

```
        string url = @"https://api2.orange.pl/sendsms/?from=509802111&to=509802111&msg=xyz";
        WebClient client = new WebClient();

        string userName = "LLLL";
        string password = "PPPP";

        string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(userName + ":" + password));
        client.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + credentials;

        //to ignore certificate error (fix from StackOverflow)
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate(object s, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
        var result = client.DownloadString(url);
```